# String split with multiple ending delimiter

Tags: string, scala, split

I am trying to parse a csv file where some of the lines may have missing fields, and I found this strange behavior:

```
scala> val s = "1,2,,,"
s: String = 1,2,,,

scala> s.split(",")
res4: Array[String] = Array(1, 2)
```

While I am expecting the result to be `Array(1,2,"","","")`. Am I missing something? If not, what is the justification of this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That behavior was inherited [from Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29). Also inherited, but not fully documented, is the Java alternative `split()` method.

```
scala> val s = "1,2,,,"
s: String = 1,2,,,

scala> s.split(",", -1)
res0: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, "", "", "")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That makes a lot of sense. According to the documentation, *If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length*. When I try the `split` method with different negative limit number, it gives me the same output. Does this mean all negative numbers as limit behave in the same way regardless of the actual value?

Comment: Yes. That's what I understand the docs to mean and, in my (very limited) experience, I've not found any different behavior for different negative numbers.